# Задача на комбинаторику. Номер размещения

Tags: комбинаторика

Помогите решить.

> По размещению найдите его номер в лексикографическом порядке.
>
> Формат ввода
>   В первой строке входных данных находятся числа N и K (1 <= K <= N <= 12). Во второй строке записаны K чисел из диапазона от 1 до N – размещение.
>
> Формат вывода
>   Выведите единственное число – номер данного размещения.
>
> Пример 1)
>
> ```
> Ввод  
> 3 2  
> 3 2  
> Вывод  
> 6
> ```
>
> Пример 2)
>
> ```
> Ввод  
> 6 4  
> 1 3 2 5  
> Вывод  
> 14
> ```

Comment: Я же не прошу сделать за меня, я прошу помочь. Халява - это когда человек ничего не сделал для решения задачи, а я хочу прийти к ее решению, но самому не получается.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Нетрудно заметить, что при генерации размещений A(n,k) в лексикографическом порядке каждый элемент стоит на первом месте A(n-1, k-1) раз.

Из этого можно заключить, что по первому элементу можно найти первичный диапазон номера размещения как

```
 r * A(n-1, k-1)
```

где `r` - номер элемента (считая с нуля) в списке [1,2,3,4,5...]

Теперь повторим то же самое со вторым элементом, только предварительно удалим использованное число из списка. И так далее, потом сложим все результаты.

```
n = 5, k = 3, A = (2,3,1)
                                                        состояние списка
(индекс двойки в начальном списке) * A(4,2) +            [1 2 3 4 5]
(индекс тройки в сжатом списке) *    A(3,1) +            [1 3 4 5] 
(индекс единицы в оставшемся списке) *  1 =              [1 4 5] 
1 * A(4,2)  + 1 * A(3,1)  + 0 =  
12 + 3 = 
15
```